# Pausing an activity that is not the current activity, this is incorrect - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an activity `BasicReactActivity` which extends `ReactActivity`. I use this activity as a base activity to host my react-native views. I have a use case where I am opening multiple instances of `BasicReactActivity` one on top of the other. I face the following exception crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: Pausing an activity that is not the current activity, this is incorrect! Current activity: BasicReactActivity Paused activity: BasicReactActivity
       at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition(Assertions.java:72)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(ReactInstanceManager.java:549)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onHostPause(ReactDelegate.java:63)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onPause(ReactActivityDelegate.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onPause(ReactActivity.java:51)
       at com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity.onPause(BasicReactActivity.java:267)
       at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:8142)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1508)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4726)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4687)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4639)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:228)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
```

Following is the code for my `onResume()` and `onPause()` of the `BasicReactActivity`:

```
public static Object REACT_DELEGATE_LOCK = new Object();

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Timber.d("{CrashDebug} Calling onPause for: " + getTag());
        Timber.d("\n");
        if(reactDelegate != null) {
            try {
                synchronized (REACT_DELEGATE_LOCK) {
                    reactDelegate.onHostPause();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.e(e);
            }
        }
    }


@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Timber.d("{CrashDebug} Calling onResume for: " + getTag());
        if(reactDelegate != null) {
            synchronized (REACT_DELEGATE_LOCK) {
                reactDelegate.onHostResume();
            }
        }
}

private String getTag() {
        if(reactDelegate.getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext() != null &&
                reactDelegate.getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()
                        .getCurrentActivity() != null) {
            return component + " : " + getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext()
                    .getCurrentActivity() + " : " + this;
        }
        return component + " : null : " + this;
    }
```

Few notes for the above code:

- I have added a lock around `reactDelegate` operations to avoid any concurrency between the `onHostPause()` and `onHostResume()` calls between two instances of `BasicReactActivity`
- `getTag()` method is usedd to trace the current state in runtime.

In one of the crashes, I see the following logs:

```
Calling onResume for: ACCOUNT_BLOCKED : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@90a3e41 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@90a3e41
Calling onResume for: ACCOUNT_BLOCKED : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@90a3e41 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@b89a25c
Calling onPause for: ACCOUNT_BLOCKED : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@90a3e41 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@b89a25c

Calling onResume for: POST_SIGNUP : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@96f6947 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@96f6947
Calling onResume for: POST_SIGNUP : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@96f6947 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@a9f057a
Calling onPause for: POST_SIGNUP : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@96f6947 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@a9f057a
```

If we observe these two lines specifically:

```
Calling onResume for: ACCOUNT_BLOCKED : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@90a3e41 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@b89a25c
Calling onPause for: ACCOUNT_BLOCKED : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@90a3e41 : com.apollorncontainer.activities.BasicReactActivity@b89a25c
```

Even after calling of `onHostResume()` for instance `b89a25c`, the `mCurrentActivity` fetched from the `ReactContext` does not change when `onHostPause()` is called.

If we check the method `onHostResume()`, only two things can cause this not to set:

- `getReactNativeHost().hasInstance()` returns false OR
- `mLifecycleState != LifecycleState.BEFORE_RESUME` and `mLifecycleState != LifecycleState.BEFORE_CREATE` (from ReactInstanceManager.moveToResumedLifecycleState)

Both above don't seem probable. Not sure, where is the problem here.

**PS:** I am using version `0.63.4` of react native.

Comment: Any updates on the solution?